# Is it possible to have a top level domain that is 2 character and not country code?

Tags: web, dns

As mention in title, I would like to know if the top level domain can be exactly 2 character and it is not country code.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "can" or "possible". Do you mean are there any? Do you mean could ICANN create one if they wanted to? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

Technically? Of course. Are there any? Well, if you're picky there's at least one that used to be a country code but no longer is (.SU). Will you ever be able to register a top-level domain that is not a country code? Almost certainly not.